# display sql custom text from table column result

Tags: sql, oracle

let say i do  `select score from table1`. this will return result

```
score
----
0
20
40
```

how to use case, to change the output to  if 0->strongly not agree 20->agree 40->very agreed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think thats what you want:

```
select 
  case 
    when score >= 40 then 'very agreed'
    when score >= 20 then 'agree'
    else 'strongly not agree'
  end
from table1
```

Answer (score 4):

This does a simple translation of fixed values:

```
select score
       , case score
              when 0 then 'strongly not agree'
              when 20 then 'agree'
              when 40 then 'very agreed'
              else 'don''t know'
         end as txt
from your_table
/
```

If you are working with ranges the syntax is slightly different:

```
select score
       , case 
              when score between 0 and 19 then 'strongly not agree'
              when score between 20 and 39 then 'agree'
              when score >= 40 then 'very agreed'
              else 'don''t know'
         end as txt
from your_table
/
```

The ELSE branch is optional but I have included it to handle NULLs or unexpected values.  If your data model enforces the appropriate constraints you might not need it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly but maybe this is what you want:

```
select decode(score,0,'Strongly not agreed',20,'Agree',40,'Very Agreed') from table1
```

Comment: Assuming he does not want any ranges, I think this is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
case when score < 20               then 'Strongly Not Agreed'
     when score between 20 and 40  then 'Agree'
     when score > 40               then 'Strongly Agreed' end
```