# CASE vs. DECODE

Tags: sql, oracle

Referring to a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193384/display-sql-custom-text-from-table-column-result), i was wondering if its always possible to replace **DECODE** by **CASE** and which one is better for performance?

Comment: I just googled "Oracle case vs decode" and found a lot of links. Basically Case is better readable, more flexible and more standard

Answer (score 57, accepted):

As always with Oracle ... [AskTom](http://asktom.oracle.com/)...

From this [post](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1243867216406)...

> Decode is somewhat obscure -- CASE is
>   very very clear.   Things that are
>   easy to do in decode are easy to do in
>   CASE, things that are hard or near 
>   impossible to do with decode are easy
>   to do in CASE.  CASE, logic wise, wins
>   hands down.

From a performance point of view seems they are about the same, again above article mentions some speed differences but without benchmarking the particular statements it's hard to say.

Comment: Another point from the same article: "decode is the function Oracle originally provided with releases of the database prior to 8.1.6.  
Starting with 816, CASE is the standard way to achieve the same results"
- So when using older versions of Oracle, CASE may not be availablle.

Comment: 8.1.6 is very old, I think 8.1.6 dates from 1999.

Comment: Thanks @TTT, that's interesting. I just got hired to convert Cognos 7 reports to Cognos 10 :). Now looking at switching DECODE statements to CASE.

Answer (score 63):

There is one big difference between `DECODE` and `CASE` and it has to do with how `NULLs` are compared.  `DECODE` will return "true" if you compare `NULL` to `NULL`.  `CASE` will not.  For example:

```
DECODE(NULL, NULL, 1, 0)
```

will return '1'.

```
CASE NULL
    WHEN NULL THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END
```

will return '0'.  You would have to write it as:

```
CASE
    WHEN NULL IS NULL THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END
```

Comment: I think this is a very important distinction. I was just reading about decode, trying to replace it with case and wondering why I'm not seeing the same results when a column value had null's. Thanks for clarifying this!

Comment: Not always, but sometimes you can fix that by using `NVL` and transforming your `null` value to something impossible for that column. Like, if it's an ID, you could transform your `null` into `-1` (but be careful with that approach. You must be sure that value is indeed impossible). Also, if your column has a check constraint, you can exhaust all options possible as cases and have `ELSE` as being what to do with `null`s

Answer (score 4):

From performance perspective, In Oracle decode and CASE does not make any difference.

But in Exadata , Decode is faster than CASE.

The Decode operation is done at storage Server level where the data is present BUT CASE is done at DB Instance level which receives data from DB storage Level.

Though that network transfer of data between Storage and DB server is less (Infiniband connection), that transfer is avoided when you use decode statment

Comment: To clarify: DECODE *can be* faster than a CASE, but a simple CASE may be translated internally to DECODE, yielding the same performance.
Reference: https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/comment/15667376/#Comment_15667376

Answer (score 4):

An old thread, I know but another interesting comparison between `CASE` and `DECODE`...  pick your poison.

```
SELECT CASE 1 WHEN '1' THEN 'A' ELSE 2 END result 

FROM DUAL 

/*
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CHAR
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*/

;

SELECT DECODE(1, '1', 'A', 2) result

FROM DUAL

/*
A
*/

;
```

Answer (score 2):

CASE is a statement and DECODE is a function
We can use the CASE in the where clause and can not use the DECODE in the where clause. 
DECODE can check equality operators only where as CASE can support all relational operators 
DECODE can be used in sql only where as CASE can be used in SQL AND PL/SQL
CASE is better than DECODE.

You can find more: http://www.oraclegeneration.com/2014/01/sql-query-interview-questions.html

Comment: -1 for "...and can not use the DECODE in the where clause." DECODE is a function and every function has a return value. And you can use that return value to check against some other value:

DECODE (tbl.field, SearchList, SomeConstOrAField, theDefault) NOT IN (some other list)

or

DECODE (tbl.field, SearchList, SomeConstOrAField, theDefault) = something

etc.

Comment: In SQL, CASE is an **expression** not a statement. The CASE statement is specific to PL/SQL. Also, DECODE is a SQL function, therefore it is an expression too, and expressions can be used in WHERE clauses.

Answer (score 0):

```
select (DECODE(NULL, NULL, 1, 0)) from dual;

select (CASE
    WHEN NULL IS NULL THEN 1
    ELSE 0

END
)
from dual;
```

both return 1

Answer (score 0):

Both the NULL to NULL Comparison returns the value as 1 instead of DECODE returning the value of 1  and CASE returning as 0.