# IIF statement in oracle sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access-2007, oracle-sqldeveloper

Have an access query that i'm trying to convert to oracle sql dev. and seems that i have my error at  **IIf(vw_gdp_currentqry.LOC='0300','F','P') AS SRCE,**  can someone help please

```
SELECT
vw_gdp_currentqry.YEAR, 
vw_gdp_currentqry.LOC, 
**IIf(vw_gdp_currentqry.LOC='0300','F','P') AS SRCE,** 
vw_gdp_currentqry.METHOD, 
vw_gdp_currentqry.current_value
FROM vw_gdp_currentqry
WHERE vw_gdp_currentqry.IND)='TOT';
```

Comment: IIF is Access specific.  You'll need to convert the syntax to something supported by the destination database.  Decode, case are two prime examples of ways to do this.

Comment: not only access but Transact SQL has built-in function IIF. The question is relevant to "generic" sql area.

Answer (score 3):

Try `decode` function

```
SELECT
vw_gdp_currentqry.YEAR, 
vw_gdp_currentqry.LOC, 
decode (vw_gdp_currentqry.LOC,'0300', 'F', 'P' ) AS SRCE,
vw_gdp_currentqry.METHOD, 
vw_gdp_currentqry.current_value
FROM vw_gdp_currentqry
WHERE vw_gdp_currentqry.IND='TOT';
```

or with `case` syntax

```
SELECT
vw_gdp_currentqry.YEAR,             
vw_gdp_currentqry.LOC, 
case vw_gdp_currentqry.LOC
  when '0300' then 'F'
  else 'P' 
end AS SRCE,
vw_gdp_currentqry.METHOD, 
vw_gdp_currentqry.current_value
FROM vw_gdp_currentqry
WHERE vw_gdp_currentqry.IND='TOT';
```

---

More information

- [Decode](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/decode.php)
- [Case](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/case.php)
- [**Case vs Decode**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193692/case-vs-decode)

Answer (score 0):

a combination of `NULLIF` and `NVL2` can be used.

One can only use this combination if `vw_gdp_currentqry.LOC` is `NOT NULL`, which it is in your case:

```
SELECT
vw_gdp_currentqry.YEAR, 
vw_gdp_currentqry.LOC, 
nvl2(nullif(vw_gdp_currentqry.LOC,'0300'),'P','F'),
vw_gdp_currentqry.METHOD, 
vw_gdp_currentqry.current_value
FROM vw_gdp_currentqry
WHERE vw_gdp_currentqry.IND='TOT';
```