# Multiple SUM values using WHERE clauses in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am writing a SQL statement against an Oracle 10g database. I want to obtain the SUM of a field with three different conditions. Can I do this with one query?

This is pseudo-SQL for what I want:

```
SELECT SUM(CP) AS CPTotal,
(SUM(CP) FROM tasks WHERE Code='P') AS CPProd,
(SUM(CP) FROM tasks WHERE Code='S') AS CPSupp
FROM tasks;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A conditional `SUM()` can be had via `CASE` statements:

```
SELECT SUM(CP) AS CPTotal,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Code = 'P' THEN CP ELSE 0 END)  AS CPProd,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Code = 'S' THEN CP ELSE 0 END)  AS CPSupp
FROM tasks;
```

The `ELSE` portion is not needed as `NULL` results when a value does not match any criteria in a `CASE` statement, and  `NULL` is ignored on aggregation, but some prefer to include it.

Comment: It looks like Goat CO and 491243 gave me the same answer, I'll accept this one because it appears to be first. Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CASE` to conditional check for the value of `code`.

```
SELECT  SUM(CP) AS CPTotal,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Code = 'P' THEN CP END) AS CPProd,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Code = 'S' THEN CP END) AS CPSupp
FROM    tasks
```

Comment: I have done the same thing with DECODE rather than CASE.  Is there a performance difference, or some other reason that CASE would be preferable?

Comment: a good answer to your question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193692/case-vs-decode