# divide a column into two based on another column value - ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

First, hope the title expresses the issue. Otherwise, any suggest is welcomed. My issue is I have the following table structure:

```
+----+------+------------------+-------------+
| ID | Name | recipient_sender |  user       |
+----+------+------------------+-------------+
|  1 | A    |                1 | X           |
|  2 | B    |                2 | Y           |
|  3 | A    |                2 | Z           |
|  4 | B    |                1 | U           |
|    |      |                  |             |
+----+------+------------------+-------------+
```

Whereby in the column `recipient_sender` the value 1 means the user is recipient, the value 2 means the user is sender.
I need to present data in the following way:

```
+----+------+-----------+---------+
| ID | Name | recipient |  sender |
+----+------+-----------+---------+
|  1 | A    | X         | Z       |
|  2 | B    | U         | Y       |
+----+------+-----------+---------+
```

I've tried self-join but it did not work. I cannot use `MAX` with `CASE WHEN`, as the number of records is too big.

**Note:** Please ignore the bad table design as it's just a simplified example of the real one

Comment: This is a fairly trivial (and abstract) problem - is this your homework? What have you tried? An email can oly have one sender but can have multiple recipients - does this aply to your real data set?

Comment: @symcbean 1 and 2 are just code to identify the user if it's for recipient or sender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
SELECT
  MIN(ID) ID
  Name, 
  max(case when recipient_sender=1 then user else null end) sender, 
  max(case when recipient_sender=2 then user else null end) recipient
From yourTable 
group by Name
```

Comment: Same as mucio'a answer, I've chosen `case when` over `decode` for readability and generality. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193692/case-vs-decode) and [here](http://www.oratable.com/decode-case-differences/)

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can try this:

```
  select min(id) id, 
         name,
         max(decode(recipient_sender, 1, user, '')) sender,
         max(decode(recipient_sender, 2, user, '')) recipient
    from t
group by name
```

You can check a demo [here on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c9a41/1).

Answer (score 0):

Create new Table (with better struct):

```
insert into <newtable> as 
select distinct 
    id, 
    name, 
    user as recipient, 
    (select user from <tablename> where id = recip.id and name = recip.name) as sender
from <tablename> recip
```

sorry, have no oracle here.

Answer (score 0):

You can select values with this query

```
SELECT t.id,
       t.name,
       case
         when t.recipient_sender = 1 then
          t.user
         ELSE
          t2.user
       END as recipient,
       case
         when t.recipient_sender = 2 then
          t.user
         ELSE
          t2.user
       END as sender
  FROM your_table t
  JOIN your_table t2
    ON t.name = t2.name
   AND t.id != t2.id
```

after this query you can add DISTINCT keyword or GROUP them ...

this query is used to join tables with column NAME but if you have some identity for message , join tables using that ,