# oracle counting null value, which is more appropriate?

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle Counting Null, both of them are returning same result, but which is more recommended? or is there better way?

```
COUNT(DECODE(RESP_CD, NULL, 'X'))
```

vs

```
NVL(SUM(DECODE(RESP_CD, NULL, 1, 0)), 0)
```

Comment: do you need the count of `NULL`? then simply user `select count(*) from your_table where resp_cd is null;`

Comment: @ajmalmhd04 in the where clause, I have two resp_cd in (NULL, 'X'). And then count two different type.

Comment: Define "appropriate" - are you asking about performance, or code readability/maintainability? Either way, I'd use neither of these methods and just prefer a simple query like @ajmalmhd04's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(n_count), SUM(x_count)
FROM
     (SELECT CASE WHEN resp_cd IS NULL THEN 1 END n_count,
          CASE WHEN resp_cd = 'x' THEN 1 END x_count
     FROM your_table
     );
```

Comment: Is it more efficient than counting within select column? Human read friendly wise, I think `COUNT(DECODE(RESP_CD, NULL, 'X'))` one looks better to me.

Comment: Suggesting you to read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193692/case-vs-decode