# Rewriting case when in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, case-expression

Hi Im trying to rewrite the following code that uses CASE WHEN. I was thinking that I can instead use decode or something else?

The code:

```
create table want as select 
case when (Var1<20 ) then 1 
when (40>Var1>=20 ) then 2 
when (Var1>=40 ) then 3 
else .
end as Var1
```

Comment: Why do you want to rewrite it? What is the problem with the current code?

Comment: Yeah using Oracle

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Im learning sql and would like to know different ways to solve problem

Answer (score 0):

This is more simply written as:

```
create table want as
    select (case when Var1 < 20 then 1 
                 when Var1 < 40 then 2 
                 when Var1 >= 40 then 3 
                 else NULL
            end) as Var1
```

Comment: Well this is same code but formatted in a better way, however  I was thiknking about using for example decode or some other function in sql.

Comment: I'm not sure if decode is officially deprecated, but everyone recommends using case instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193692/case-vs-decode

Answer (score 0):

`decode()` only supports equality. One of the reasons why we welcomed `case()` when it was introduced back in the day was precisely because it allowed us to test greater than and less than.

However it is possible to nest `decode()` calls and combine them with other functions to achieve the same outcome. This ...

```
select id
     , var1
     , decode(greatest(var1,20), 20, 1, 
              decode(least(var1,40), 40, 3, 2 )) as trans_var
from tab
/
```

... implements the logic of your `case()` statement:

```
select id
       , var1
       , (case when Var1 < 20 then 1 
                 when Var1 < 40 then 2 
                 when Var1 >= 40 then 3 
                 else NULL
            end) as trans_var
from tab
/
```

[SQL Fiddle demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ad2a0/3)