# What is exactly difference between a 'statement' and a 'function' in oracle sql?

Tags: oracle, case, decode

While reading upon the difference between decode function and `CASE WHEN` statement, I got confused while understanding that if both give the same result for a simple equation like the following:

```
DECODE(col1, 'ABC', 'DEF', 'OTHERS' ) AS COL2

CASE WHEN COL1 = 'ABC' THEN 'DEF'
        ELSE 'OTHERS'   
     END AS COL2
```

Then what is the difference between the functionality of a function and a statement?

p.s. I am aware Case is capable of taking more complex equations... my question here is more about understanding difference between function and statement.

Comment: `CASE` is an *expression*, not a statement

Comment: Thank you. many websites including stack overflow (stackoverflow.com/questions/3193692/case-vs-decode ) had users suggesting case is a statement, so I got confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL, there is no such thing as a "CASE statement". Your example is a `CASE` **expression**. (`CASE` statements do exist in PL/SQL.)

The documentation states "An expression is a combination of one or more values, operators, and SQL functions that evaluates to a value." So a SQL function is not different from an expression, it is a specific type of expression.

Note that `DECODE` and `CASE` behave differently when comparing NULL values: `DECODE` considers two NULLs to be "the same", which is an exception to the rule that comparing a NULL to anything has an "unknown" result.

```
with data(a, b) as (
  select 1,1 from dual union all
  select 1,null from dual union all
  select null,1 from dual union all
  select null, null from dual
)
select a, b,
  decode(a,b,'same','different') decode_result,
  case when a = b then 'same' else 'different' end case_result
from data;

A      B      DECODE_RESULT CASE_RESULT
------ ------ ------------- -----------
1      1      same          same
1      (null) different     different
(null) 1      different     different
(null) (null) same          different
```

Comment: Actually many websites including stack overflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193692/case-vs-decode ) had users suggesting case is a statement, so I got confused. Your explanation makes it clear, thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation :-) Are you aware of differences in implementation, in database engine, between CASE and DECODE which can have an impact on performance?

Comment: Marcin, the only difference I can think of would be in the evaluation of the different conditions. Suppose a CASE contains several WHEN conditions that use lots of resources: if all of the conditions are evaluated no matter what, then performance is worse than if evaluations stop at the first hit. I believe both CASE and DECODE stop as soon as possible, so I would not expect any noticeable difference in performance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty much sure that `CASE` didn't exist in pre-9i Oracle database versions so you **had to** use `DECODE`.

No difference, they will both do the same job, but `CASE` is simpler to maintain. `DECODE` can grow to a real *monster* when complex things have to be done, with nested `DECODE`s so you probably know what you're doing while typing that statement, but a month later you're in deep trouble as you don't know what belongs to what, which closing bracket is closing which open bracket, ... real nightmare.

But, for simple things, it is quite OK. Saves some typing.

Answer (score 0):

A function is simply some functionality capsuled. With a function you can call a functionality from anywhere without spelling it out explicitely. There are predefined functions like `DECODE()` or you can [define functions yourself](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5009.htm).

A statement is something like `select 1 from dual` and may contain functions (`select decode(col1,'1','yes','no') from mytable`).

The statement is (as long as you aren't in a [block](http://www.datenbank-plsql.de/plsql-block.htm), which itself may contain several statements) an order you send to the DB, a function is kindof an instruction what to do with the given arguments.